# Звуковая схема и звуковая запись к слову "ягода"?

Tags: фонетика

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить звуковую схему слова "ягода"!

Comment: Валентин,я не уверен, что речь идет о транскрипционной записи.

Comment: Тогда я не знаю, что спрашивают.

Answer (score 3):

Хорошо бы спрашивающему указать, для какого класса задание. Подозреваю, что звуковая схема - это из начальной школы, они там специальными значками обозначают, надо ориентироваться на учебник. Звуковая запись - это транскрипция, но в учебниках, по которым мы работаем, например, уже с пятого класса обозначают заударные гласные после твердого как Ъ. Практически вузовская транскрипция. Поэтому хорошо бы знать класс. учебник и требования учителя. Многие учителя, несмотря на требования программы и учебника, используют традиционные знаки. То, что приведено в ответе behemothus - это фонетический разбор (опять же по новым требованиям должны записать /y**а**гъдъ/. Буквы не пишутся, т.к. считается, что фонетический разбор - это анализ звуковой стороны. Орфографически слово записывается после разбора, указывается количество звуков и букв, причина несовпадения.

Comment: Ларf, все это хорошо, но есть одно "маленькое но". Эти задания в массе ни из учебника, а с родственных ресурсов. Я никогда не поверю, что десятки учащихся одновременно озаботились разбором слова "ягода" и пошли искать ответы в интернете. Что касается значков-рисунков, то о них можно долго говорить, но если учащийся не в состоянии понять ответ иначе как нарисованный с помощью красно-сине-зелёных квадратиков, то на кай оно надо, это цветное образование?! Скоро дойдем до того, что вместо русского языка начнём преподавать язык этих квадратиков.

Comment: А мой ответ списан с первого же *принятого* ответа, на мэйле, кажется. Мне бы и в голову не пришло самому такую фигню рисовать. 
Я вообще не хотел отвечать, пока не понял, что Валентин и его ответ явно "не в теме".

Answer (score 0):

Схема такова: ягода — *[йагода].*

Answer (score 0):

Ягода - 3 слога (ударение на 1-ый слог)
я(й)-согл., звон., мягк.
(а)-глас., удар.
г(г)-согл., звон., тв.
о(а)-глас., безуд.
д(д)-согл., тв., звон.
а(а)-глас., безуд.
//------------------------------
5 букв, 6 звуков.
(Й А" Г А Д А)

Comment: А-а-а, такое. Я что-то не подумал об этом.